# Why a different SHA-1 for the same file under windows or linux?

Tags: windows, linux, hash, msysgit, sha1

Why on the same machine computing the SHA-1 hash of the same file produces two completely different SHA-1 hashes in windows and inside a msysgit Git bash?

Doesn't the SHA-1 algorithm was intended to produce the same hash for the same file in all OSes?

On windows (with HashCheck):
File hello.txt
22596363b3de40b06f981fb85d82312e8c0ed511

Inside a msysgit's Git bash windows (same machine, same file):

$ git hash-object hello.txt
3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad

Comment: If you configure Git correctly then then text file line endings are treated correctly. See http://help.github.com/dealing-with-lineendings/ -- NB This applies to *nix users as well!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git adds [a header](http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html#object_storage) ("blob ", the length, then null) before calculating the SHA-1.  See [this blog post](http://alecthegeek.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/handy-hack-calculating-git-sha1-on-files/) for how to emulate the calculation outside git.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew! The fun story is that yesterday I received my copy of Pro Git from Amazon ;-)
I started to read it online exactly the moment after having read your answer here: aka NOW!